# How do I get a high-quality version of my account iChat icon?

Tags: photos, ichat, accounts

I'm looking for the file that corresponds to my account photo (this is also my iChat icon).

[image]

Comment: So your trying to get the actual image file?

Comment: yup, that's exactly what i'm trying to do (stupid length requirement lol..)

Comment: Your image link is dead — please can you upload it using the official image uploader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following "generic" command, when copy-pasted directly into Terminal and run without modification, creates a small file named MyAccountPic.jpg on the current user's Desktop:

```
dscl . -read /Users/`id -un` JPEGPhoto | tail -1 | xxd -r -p > ~/Desktop/MyAccountPic.jpg
```

Comment: Links often break over time. Please summarize the contents of external sites in your answer rather than simply linking.

Comment: Okay, is that better?